# Sorting in Cassandra with editable fields

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I understand that Cassandra has the sorting feature using clustering key.

I have a 'username' field which I configured as 'Clustering key' and It is sorted in Ascending order as per the need.

But I need to edit the username which is not possible.

1) Could you please let me know any alternative way for this so that I can perform the sorting of the username in Cassandra.

2) Also, Does secondary index help in sorting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, you cannot change the value of a clustering key (or any key as a matter of fact). Also, server-side ordering is only possible by the clustering key. Secondary indexes don't help in sorting.

The only workaround I see is to delete the old record and create a new one:

```
DELETE FROM users WHERE key = 'key' AND username = 'oldusername';
INSERT INTO users (key, username, ...) VALUES ('key', 'newusername', ...);
```

You can execute the two operations in a BATCH to make them atomic:

```
BEGIN BATCH
  DELETE FROM users WHERE key = 'key' AND username = 'oldusername';
  INSERT INTO users (key, username, ...) VALUES ('key', 'newusername', ...);
APPLY BATCH
```

Comment: Can you please explain this point : You can execute the two operations in a BATCH to make them atomic.

Comment: [BATCH operations](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlBatch.html) combine multiple DML statements to ensure atomicity - if any of the operations fail within the batch, then the others are also rolled back. I added a code example to the answer above.